# Are the last three books laws of the Pentateuch related?

Tags: law, torah

There are verses in these last books that seem to expand on each others laws. I think the best example is verses like Leviticus 20:9 and Deuteronomy 21:18–21,where they both talk about the punishment of son who done wrong to their parents. However, Leviticus is short, while Deuteronomy seems to expand on Leviticus and be more detailed. So are these last books laws related and expand on each other or their their own laws separately?